# How to load Zend 2 classes on autoloader

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-db

Previously, i am using zend 1.x. I am able to autoload zend classes using the below code.

```
// autoload class from Zend Lib
require_once ABSPATH.'/classes/Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php'; 
$loader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();    
 try{
// database connection      
$dbo = Zend_Db::factory('pdo_mysql', array( 
        'host'     => DB_HOST, 
        'username' => DB_USER, 
        'password' => DB_PW, 
        'dbname'   => DB_PREFIX.DB_NAME
    )); 
$dbo->getConnection();
// save database adapter for easy usage in other classes
Zend_Db_Table::setDefaultAdapter($dbo);
Zend_Registry::set('db', $dbo);

}catch(Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception $e){
print $e;
 //header("Location: http://www.google.com/error/");
}
```

I am upgrading to zend 2 as the classes might be better. May i know how do i autoload them?

Comment: hi! i am not using zend framework, however, i am using their classes as a standalone in my custom framework..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just using ZF2 as a standalone library without employing the full MVC framework, then autoloading is fairly straightforward:

1. Make sure that the `Zend` directory is on your php `include_path`.
2. Push an autoloader using `spl_autoload_register`

The following is essentially what `Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader::loadClass()` does when functioning as a fallback autloader:

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    $f = stream_resolve_include_path(str_replace('\\', '/', $class) . '.php');
    if ($f !== false) {
        return include $f;
    }
    return false;
});
```

This would use the PSR-1 autloading mechanism for all classes, not just the Zend classes.

Alternatively, you could just do the following:

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader/StandardAutoloader.php';
$autoloader = new Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader(array(
    'fallback_autoloader' => true,
));
$autoloader->register();
```

As above, this will apply PSR-1 autoloading to *all* classes. If you want this mechanism for the Zend classes only, then pass `'fallback_autoloader' => false`.

Comment: hi, i am adding the above code in,  new Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader give me a syntax error.

Comment: Correcting the `require_once` call. Had a slash instead of a dot.

Comment: Another thought: ZF2 requires at least PHP 5.3. Can you confirm by running `php --version`?

Comment: thanks! the autoloader works, another important questions. how do i load zend_db classes like the code as shown?


$dbo = Zend_Db::factory('pdo_mysql', array( 
         'host'     => DB_HOST, 
         'username' => DB_USER, 
         'password' => DB_PW, 
         'dbname'   => DB_PREFIX.DB_NAME
     )); 
 $dbo->getConnection();

Comment: This code - referencing `Zend_Db` - looks like ZF1. Using both ZF1 and ZF2 together is possible, but it is a whole different issue. See http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/migration/zf1_zf2_parallel.html

Comment: is it advisable to use both? what is zf1 and zf2? is zf2 better than zf1?

Comment: ZF stands for "Zend Framework". I would choose to use ZF2 only.

Comment: Starting to get really out of SO scope here. I prefer ZF2 largely because of PHP 5.3 namespaces which I find more elegant than ZF1's PEAR-style prefixing scheme.

Comment: Also, per-component use via Composer.

Comment: Thanks @DavidWeinraub, I thinks there is an extra ")" at the end of: spl_autoload_register(function($class))

Answer (score 1):

You can also load the individual components through [Composer](http://getcomposer.org) and then you just need to include `require 'vendor/autoload.php';` at the start of your execution script.

Answer (score 0):

I would Suggest you to study a skeleton App Provided by ZF2,
I am not much aware About ZF1 but as far as i know ZF2 has its own mechanism of Auto Loading,
as far as Auto Loading is concerned when you follow Skeleton Application you will notice that there is a **Config\application.config.php** this is the file where we load All the Modules etc. As a sample i will load my file below. As far as setting connections etc is concerned you will find them under them same directory tree i.e "Config\local or Config\Global".

```
 <?php
return array(
// This should be an array of module namespaces used in the application.
'modules' => array(
    'ZendDeveloperTools',
    'DoctrineModule',
    'DoctrineORMModule',
    'Application',
    'Administration',
    'Account',
    'Manufacturing',
    'GridMain',
),

// These are various options for the listeners attached to the ModuleManager
'module_listener_options' => array(
    'module_paths' => array(
        './module',
        './vendor',
    ),
    'config_glob_paths' => array(
        'config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php',
    ),
),


);
```